# Is there any difference between $('.className > button') and $('.className').children('button')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

In jQuery is there any difference between

```
$('.className > button')
```

and

```
$('.className').children('button')
```

Or are these just alternate syntaxes to get the same thing?

Comment: first one uses css selector and the second one uses jQuery function.

Comment: That much is obvious...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not in terms of what you'll actually end up with, but the first one can be offloaded in its entirety to the browser's built-in CSS selection engine, whereas the second one requires jQuery to do more work and involves more object creation and cleanup. It's unlikely to matter unless you're doing this with a lot of elements in, say, a `mousemove` handler, though, if even then...

Comment: Is jquery really leveraging the browsers CSS engine? I always thought the CSS selectors are parsed by a JS library

Comment: @fschmengler: If the browser provides `querySelectorAll` and you don't use a jQuery-specific selector like `:eq` or `:disabled`, yes, jQuery uses the built-in engine rather than its own because it's *dramatically* faster that way. jQuery only falls back to Sizzle if it has to because the browser doesn't have `querySelectorAll` (unlikely, even IE8 has it) or if you use a jQuery-specific selector.

Comment: Sizzle, that was it. I hoped that my information was just outdated, thanks for the update!